# Iterate over files over several directories to extract data

Tags: python, loops

I have a series of files that are nested as shown in the attached image. For each "inner" folder (e.g. like the 001717528 one), I want to extract a row of data from each the FITS files and create a CSV file that contains all the rows, and name that CSV file after the name of the "inner" folder (e.g. 001717528.csv that has data from the 18 fits files). The data-extracting part is easy but I have trouble coding the iteration.

I don't really know how to iterate over both the outer folders such as the 0017 and inner folders, and name the csv files as I want.

[image: Screen-cap of my files]

My code is looking like this:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('../kepler'):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        if filepath.endswith(".fits"):
            extract data
        write to csv file
```

Apparently this will iterate over all files in the kepler folder so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep track of how far you've walked into the directory structure, you can count the file path delimiter (`os.sep`). In your case it's `/` because you're on a Mac.

```
for path, dirs, _ in os.walk("../kepler"):      
  if path.count(os.sep) == 2:
    # path should be ../kepler/0017  
    for dir in dirs:  
      filename = dir + ".csv"
      data_files = os.listdir(path + os.sep + dir)
      for file in data_files:
        if file.endswith(".fits"):
          # Extract data
          # Write to CSV file
```

As far as I can tell this meets your requirements, but let me know if I've missed something.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I got the hang of it. Will check it out and tell you if there's any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it should print the file path of all your ".fits" files:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

import os
base_dir = './test'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_dir, topdown=False):
  for name in files:
    if name.endswith(".fits"):
      file_path = os.path.join(root, name) #path of files
      print(file_path)
    # do your treatment on file_path
```

All you have to do is add your specific treatment.

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your help. The problem with this is that it doesn't discriminate between files from different subfolders but instead group them altogether. What I need is to treat files from different subfolders separately and create a csv file for each subfolder. Can you show me how to do this? Or maybe I misunderstood your answer. If so I would appreciate if you could specify how to achieve that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My bad I didn't understood your question, I will update my answer soon. Does @staples answer solve your problem?

Comment: Hi Thomas, @staples answered my question. Thanks a lot!